# Any internal medicine to get rid of maggots in dogs?

Tags: dogs, medicines, parasites, infections

There's a 6 month puppy in my area and he's been infected with maggots in his right rear leg. He's too scared of humans so i cant go near him and apply any ointment or spray. So is there any internal medicine which can be used to get rid of maggots and can also be mixed in his food?

Comment: Your best bet is to get a humane cage trap like [this](http://www.havahart.com/store/animal-traps/dogs), bait it with food, capture the puppy, and take it to a vet.  Be sure to check the trap often, especially during the day, so anything caught won't get too dehydrated/overheated/etc.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not a strictly internal/oral medication that can be used to treat maggots living in a live dog. The condition is called [fly strike or Myiasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myiasis) it can be [fatal if untreated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myiasis#Life_cycle), there has been [some success](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myiasis#Treatment) orally with [Ivermectin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ivermectin) in treating cattle, but there is some indication that dying larvae excrete toxins that can be fatal so close monitoring of the animal is required.

Most remedies involve physically removing the maggots, followed by treatment for related issues.

Comment: It's a wound....

Comment: Yes, myiasis often occurs on open wounds.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand Maggots only eat dead tissue, but with him so shy it would be difficult to treat him, maybe you can talk to a vet, there are some suggestions from this site. However all of them require hands on treatment, since basically its the wound that needs treating, cleaning and covering, probably no medicine can substitute that...

**from wiki pet, source below:
Treatment*be

1. Restrain your pet if necessary. Maggot infested areas of skin can be very painful, and a pet may bite as a reflex. maybe make a makeshift muzzle.
2. Use blunt tip scissors or electric clippers and clip the affected areas to remove soiled and matted hair. Fur traps bacteria and keeps re infecting the wound.
3. Remove all maggots with blunt-nosed tweezers, a gauze pad, or tissue. Wear a pair of disposable medical gloves to avoid touching the worms.
4. Wash infected areas with Betadine solution and dry the dog. If you are using water to flush the wound, flush the area for at least 15 minutes. As the maggots escape the wound to avoid drowning, you are then able to easily pick them off. Water will rinse away any remaining fly eggs that haven't hatched.
5. Then spray or shampoo the dog using a non-alcohol based product that contains pyrethrins and check closely for remaining maggots.
6. Topical antibiotic ointments such as Neosporin can be used to assist in fighting infection. Be sure this ointment is out of "licking range" to avoid the oral consumption of the medicine.

Dogs with infected wounds should be treated with oral antibiotics. If the dog is debilitated, her health and nutrition must be improved to bring about a cure.

Cleaning maggots out of a wound is only the first step, and often, the tissue damage is severe. Healing may take a long time, and wound care is important to ensure that more infection doesn't develop.

A product designed for horses called Dy's Liquid Bandage is the veterinarians' choice for treating invasive, massive, or slow to heal wounds in cats and dogs. It is a combination of soothing herbs in an olive oil and beeswax formula. Olive oil is easily absorbed into the skin and carries the medicinal herbs along with it, while the beeswax covers the wound with a waterproof barrier that repels flies but allows air to penetrate to heal the wound.

The ointment works well on minor wounds, like a scrape or hot spot so it is a great home remedy to keep on hand.
Prevention
If your pet has a history of problems with maggots and had a very thick coat that hides sores, it may be a good idea to have a professional dog groomer give them a trim for the summer months when maggots are most active.
Support
Please contact your veterinarian or a professional pet groomer if you have questions about this condition.

http://www.wiki-pet.com/health/dog/condition/index.php?condition_id=62
**You need to check with your vet**...good luck

Comment: what kind of sleepy medicine should i give and also i am currently giving him [this](http://www.unitedpharmacies.com/Cefpet-Cefpodoxime-Proxetil.html)

Comment: As stated you need a vet to advise you, I have no idea, Im not a vet.

Comment: Yes [maggots only eat dead tissue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maggot_therapy), so they may be doing more good than harm. It's the wound you need to be concerned about.

Comment: I thought I remembered that about maggots, but wasn't sure so didn't post. The idea of tranquilizing him for treatment makes some sense to me if you're sure you'll be there when it takes effect, but you _definitely_ need a vet involved in that case to recommend drug and dosage and probably to supervise.  A humane trap would scare him more but might be a better alternative.

Comment: Yes good point @keshlam, a humane trap might be better (would be terrible for him to fall asleep and not be able to find him...)

Comment: its a wound....

Comment: @mhwombat **Only some species of maggot eat only dead tissue!** Other species eat both dead and living tissue.  This is not something I would leave to chance.

Comment: @mhwombat augurar is correct.  see [Fly strike/Myiasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myiasis)

Answer (score 1):

Maggot infestation can be cured.
It's very natural that the animal wouldn't let you come near it as it is in extreme pain as the maggots continuously feed upon its flesh, skin and organs.
So first it is necessary to kill the maggots.
Get medicinal turpentine oil from a veterinary medicine shop. Pour a cap or two of that oil over the wound depending upon the size and depth of the affected area.
After 8 hours you will see that all the maggots are dead and they have tried to come out of the infested area.

Comment: This is not a guaranteed cure, many maggots could still be alive inside the wound and continue to cause a lot of pain. Also if the dog licks it, digestion issues can occur.

Comment: The OP also specified that a topical remedy was not acceptable.