# Will Myiasis cause death?

Tags: dogs, diseases, parasites

I have a crossbreed dog of Lhasa and Pomeranian. He was a very friendly dog. He had a wound nearby and we applied medicines, but somehow maggot infection occurred. Now he is quite angry and he cannot be controlled. Although my vet has promised me that he will take care of him.

Will the maggot infection kill him or is it likely the vet will cure him?

Comment: Related [Any internal medicine to get rid of maggots in dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10047)

Comment: I made a couple of edits to improve the readability of the question, It could still use more, I expect someone else may edit it also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any internal medicine to get rid of maggots in dogs?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10047/any-internal-medicine-to-get-rid-of-maggots-in-dogs)

Comment: Please note - this is a question about Myiasis - which is fly strike under the skin. It is not a duplicate of The internal medicine Question, Nor is it a duplicate of this https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18565/maggots-on-back-of-the-dog

Answer (score 1):

So, this question depends on the severity of the Myiasis and how much deep tissue has been damaged, so I will give you a broad answer, that may help you and others in the future. Usually a bacterial infection spreads quicker than the rapid spread of the larvae, and bacterial infection can definitely kill an animal. If your vet has said he/she thinks treatment is the best option for your pup (versus being in too much pain, too much suffering, or too far gone thus suggesting euthanasia) then I would try my best to keep the faith in his educated opinion.

Since I don't have pictures, or am able to see a blood panel test, or blood/tissue culture to see what type of infection or bacteria is growing and how the body is reacting- I would suggest IF you are concerned enough you could always get a second opinion from another vet.  Subcutaneous infections can get into the bloodstream, spread to the spine, brain, other organs etc. I have seen a dog go blind from Myiasis from the location of where the infestation and infection took place. I would take this seriously either way, no matter the severity, because even if "death" (as you asked) isn't the outcome, there could be other outcomes that affect your pup forever. I would try your vets treatment plan.

You did the right thing by taking him to the vet after topical solutions didn't work.