# Maggots on back of the dog

Tags: dogs, health, medicines, parasites

I have a 4 year old german shepherd dog with lots of bushy hair. He has been infected  with maggots for the past 1 month or more. I'm treating him with Turpentine and the vet gave him some antibiotics.

He is still getting infected all around the earlier site on his back. What can I do?

Comment: What is causing the infection? Can you carefully cut the fur where he's infected? Also turpentine may be a bit severe on the skin. You can try a solution with tea tree oil and give him a good bath with a medicated dog shampoo. Keep any bedding clean, washed and sprayed with a suitable dog approved insect repellant.

Comment: Please note - this  question is not a duplicate of  https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17687/will-myiasis-cause-death - which is  about Myiasis - which is fly strike under the skin. It is not a duplicate of The internal medicine Question https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10047/any-internal-medicine-to-get-rid-of-maggots-in-dogs as it's not asking for internal medical solutions.

Comment: Does the dog *still* have maggots?

Answer (score 4):

This can be a lengthy process, here are the steps **you** and your **veterinarian** need to take.

1) Shave the area around the wound, it needs to breathe and be kept clean, having all that hair in the area will only make things worse.

2) Capstar is a good medication for maggots, it needs to be given rectally and **not** orally. Injectable ivermectin can work as well however there can be some serious side-effects with it.

3) With sterile hemostats/forceps remove visible maggots from the wound.

4) Flush wound with a diluted betadine flush (betadine is cytotoxic so needs to be heavily diluted). Scrub around the wound with gauze soaked in chlorhexadine.

5) Continue with long-term antibiotics until issue is resolved.

6) If he's an outdoor dog he needs to be relocated to a clean, indoor environment where no flies can get at him.

I haven't seen a maggot case in years, I will update with more tricks once I get back to work on Tuesday October 10, will ask the DVM.